# I want to fetch data from big query from repeated field into repeated

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to fetch data from big query from repeated field into repeated. I have Answers field with repeated in that I have again a options field which is repeated too. In option field I have a answer No, I want to count that answer in number field.
But I got an error:

```
WITH
  data AS(
  SELECT
    task.workflowInfo.answers AS ans
  FROM
    `Test_2019_02_07` ),
  data_2 AS(
  SELECT
    ans.options.answerNo AS aac
  FROM
    data 
    )
SELECT * FROM data_2
```

But got an error:

```
Cannot access field options on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<question STRUCT<normalization STRUCT<dbInfo STRUCT<id STRING>, name STRUCT<name STRUCT<firstName STRING, middleNames STRING, lastName STRING>>, displayName STRUCT<name STRUCT<firstName STRING, middleNames STRING, lastName STRING>>, ...>, displayText STRUCT<name STRUCT<firstName STRING, middleNames STRING, lastName STRING>, canonicalName STRUCT<firstName STRING, middleNames STRING, lastName STRING>>, questionNo INT64, ...>, actualAnswer STRUCT<tenScaleRatingAnswer STRING, threeScaleRatingAnswer STRING, fiveScaleRatingAnswer STRING, ...>, goodReasons ARRAY<STRUCT<normalization STRUCT<dbInfo STRUCT<id STRING>, name STRUCT<name STRUCT<firstName STRING, middleNames STRING, lastName STRING>>, displayName STRUCT<name STRUCT<firstName STRING, middleNames STRING, lastName STRING>>, ...>, displayText STRUCT<canonicalName STRUCT<firstName STRING, middleNames STRING, lastName STRING>>, answerNo INT64>>, ...>> at [9:9]
```

How I solve this please help.

Comment: You need to look into the UNNEST operator
you can start with https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#unnest and https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#flattening-arrays

Comment: please can anybody tell me how i fetch repated into repeted element